# Chapel Dataframes basic example

Tags: chapel

I know that Chapel Dataframes are a new, relatively undocumented feature, but is there a basic example some place?  The test suite [here](https://github.com/chapel-lang/chapel/blob/master/test/library/standard/DataFrames/DataFrames.chpl) is a bit hard to follow.

Comment: What is a data frame?

Comment: It's an object over a CSV, but I don't know much about them yet.  There are some tests but not much else.

Comment: Your link is pointing to the actual implementation rather than a test. Dataframes did not make it into the 1.18 release, but the implementation lives in this test directory for now. See https://github.com/chapel-lang/chapel/tree/master/test/library/standard/DataFrames/psahabu for the actual tests and their python-pandas equivalents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of the current release (Chapel 1.18) Chapel Dataframes are not yet a supported feature; rather, they are still a work-in-progress.

Comment: You make me sad, but I'll forgive you.